# How to get implementation address after deployProxy()? (@open-zepplin/hardhat-upgrades)

Tags: openzeppelin, hardhat, openzeppelin-sdk

I'm deploying my token using the proxy pattern via hardhat-upgrades.

```
const TokenFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory('MyToken');
const token = await upgrades.deployProxy(TokenFactory);

const result = await token.deployed();
```

Next I want to verify the contract on etherscan using `hardhat-etherscan`

```
await run('verify:verify', {
   address: token.address,
   constructorArguments: []
});
```

The problem is `token.address` points to the proxy. From what I understand the proxy doesnt need to be verified, but rather the implementation does.

But I can't seem to find a way to get the implementation address.

Where is this elusive address and how can I access it programmatically after deploying the proxy?

Comment: Ask a hack you could use my hardhat-upgrades template which will give you all the dependencies and needed scripts for getting started quickly developing upgradeable smart contracts, including automatic verification: https://github.com/gabrielstoica/hardhat-upgrades/tree/main

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the below,

```
import { getImplementationAddress } from '@openzeppelin/upgrades-core';
    
const currentImplAddress = await getImplementationAddress(provider, proxyAddress);
```

Answer (score 12):

You can also use the hardhat upgrades plugin for the same effect as the accepted answer:

```
import { ethers, upgrades } from "hardhat";

const currentImplAddress = await upgrades.erc1967.getImplementationAddress(proxyAddress);
```